# sub writing out matching values vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm working on a sub which finds matching values in a given range and writes them out.
The problem is that my version writes out every value in the range, so I would appreciate a little help in changing that so that it just write out the matching ones.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub azonos2a()
Dim rng As range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("range", , , , , , , 8)

Dim a

Dim c
Dim d

With ActiveSheet


For Each c In rng.Cells
    For Each d In rng.Cells
        If c.Value = d.Value Then
            MsgBox c.Value
        End If
    Next
Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The `With ActiveSheet` seems pointless

Comment: Try dimming c and d as ranges aswell. and removing .Cells from rng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your nested loop you are comparing every cell in the range to every cell in the range -- including itself. You need a nested loop in which the inner loop passes over different values than the outer loop, but in such a way that all distinct pairs of cells are compared. The easiest way to do this is with indices:

```
Sub azonos2a()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("range", , , , , , , 8)

Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
n = rng.Cells.Count

For i = 1 To n - 1
    For j = i + 1 To n
        If rng.Cells(i).Value = rng.Cells(j).Value Then
            MsgBox rng.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```